# Cómo puedo insertar una imagen en una base de datos de SQL Server usando jsp?

Tags: sql-server, jsp

Necesito insertar una imagen en una base de datos de SQL Server, pero no sé como hacerlo. Alguien puede explicarme cómo puedo hacerlo? o cual es la mejor manera de hacerlo? Ya busque por todos lados y no encuentro una forma...

Comment: En programación es importante saber separar los problemas grandes en problemas pequeños. En este caso tienes A) subir una imagen (o simplemente un fichero, que sea una imagen o no da lo mismo) a un servidor java y B) guardar una imagen (o fichero) en BD. No me creo que no seas capaz de encontrar ejemplos de como hacer cada cosa...

Comment: El problema no es eso, el problema es encontrar como hacerlo a una base de datos sql server, puesto que cómo subirlo a MySQL se encuentra en cualquier sitio.

Comment: Puedes subir tu archivo a un servidor por FTP, guardar la ruta en tu BD y acceder mediante un SELECT a la ruta y acceder a la ruta en tu proyecto JSP donde puedes mostrarla. La otra manera es convertir la imagen a bytes guardarlo y cuando quieras mostrarlo convertir de bytes a image, pero creo que esto consumirá mucho espacio en tu BD.